# Can't Build Vue Project because "allocation failure"

Tags: node.js, vue.js, ubuntu, webpack

I have a VPS and want to build a vue-cli and after I ran 'npm i',
then 'npm run build'
it shows these errors and I want to limit the memory usage of vue-cli to fit the VPS specs

I use Ubuntu 19 and my memory is 1 GB

```
> promoting_activation_front@0.1.0 build /var/www/promoting_frontend
> vue-cli-service build


⠙  Building for production...Starting type checking service...
Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit
⠦  Building for production...
<--- Last few GCs --->

[17469:0x5f3ce60]    73438 ms: Mark-sweep 485.2 (497.5) -> 482.1 (498.0) MB, 1062.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.123, current mu = 0.034) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[17469:0x5f3ce60]    74265 ms: Mark-sweep 485.7 (498.0) -> 482.7 (498.5) MB, 810.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.078, current mu = 0.021) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x145cc79]
Security context: 0x1f245e040921 <JSObject>
    1: _walk [0x94962f2c7b9] [/var/www/promoting_frontend/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:~1] [pc=0x27639ec77dca](this=0x29c90f60d7f1 <AST_Binary map = 0xba64fdfe151>,0x335b0e457b71 <bn map = 0x3d73333ce401>)
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200203.130003.17469.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0xa9d570 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0xa9f832 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xc0758e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xc07909 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xdb5e15  [node]
 6: 0xdb64a6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xdc4d19 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xdc5b55 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xdc862c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
11: 0x10dc52e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x145cc79  [node]
Aborted (core dumped)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 134
npm ERR! promoting_activation_front@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the promoting_activation_front@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason was my small memory when I upgrade it the error doesn't happen